# Is it possible to use jquery drag and drop to re-position an item and resize that item to fit a boundary?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, resize

For example, the Windows taskbar.  You can drag it to the left, right, top, and bottom.  The taskbar automatically keeps the same size, just goes horizontal or vertical.  I'm looking for a menu or any item with an example really, in jquery that I can do that with.  I've found lots of menus and drag and drop examples.

I have not found any drag and drop anything that resizes, especially based upon the size of the window, like the Windows taskbar.

Thanks for any help.

I have searched:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749685/drag-and-drop-with-resize-jquery

many websites with drag and drop and resize but nothing like I mentioned...the menu idea was just and example as was the taskbar.

edit:  only thing I found was this, but it does not look to smooth...
http://sagifogel.brinkster.net/

Comment: @SpYk3HH Do you have any more information?

Comment: Dude, I was being a bit facetious with my answer earlier because it seems you're looking for a "pre-designed" solution. Fact is, you'll need to do some "work" on this one. When I have more time later, if no one else has answered this, I'll make a working example, until then, please, try some things yourself and get into the "code-work" of it all.

Comment: @SpYk3HH of course I want something already made.  Why do I have to re-invent the wheel?  I have no problem with working.  I have a problem with unnecessary work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You might want to take a look at [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)

Keep in mind that you can make your sortable lists horizontal, which describes your requirements.

Comment: I don't see it re-sizing though, automatically, based on where I drag and drop it to.

Comment: I need it to do like the windows taskbar.